# Влияние ключевого слова volatile

Tags: java, volatile

```
  public class Solution {
    public static int totalSpeechCount = 200;
    public static int utterancesPerSpeech = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Politician ivanov = new Politician("Иванов");

        Politician petrov = new Politician("Петров");
        Politician sidorov = new Politician("Сидоров");

        while (ivanov.getSpeechCount() + petrov.getSpeechCount() + sidorov.getSpeechCount() < totalSpeechCount) {
        }

        System.out.println(ivanov);
        System.out.println(petrov);
        System.out.println(sidorov);
    }

    public static class Politician extends Thread {
        private  volatile int utteranceCount;

        public Politician(String name) {
            super(name);
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            while (utteranceCount < totalSpeechCount * utterancesPerSpeech) {
                utteranceCount++;
            }
        }

        public int getSpeechCount() {
            return utteranceCount / utterancesPerSpeech;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s сказал речь %d раз", getName(), getSpeechCount());
        }
    }
}
```

Каким образом здесь влияет volatile над выполнением программы!?
Интересно то, что программа выполняется и без volatile, только гораздо дольше. Я понимаю вопрос про то, что если переменная volatile, то другие потоки будут видеть изменения этой переменной. Но ведь здесь эта переменная объекта класса и другие потоки не пытаются ее менять. В чем смысл!? К тому же мы все равно производим инкрементирование этой переменной, т.е. не атомарную операцию. или я чего то не понимаю?!
UPD 1: Интересно еще то, что без volatile к utteranceCount вывода программы ждать очень долго (может и вообще его не будет), однако если запускать программу через дебаггер с брейкпоинтом в любом месте, то все выводится быстро. Прям видно, как быстро набирается количество высказываний политиков (getSpeechCount()). С volatile высказывания ко всем трем политикам набираются равномерно, без соответственно в разброс.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это Java? (метку языка добавьте к вопросу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то переменная может читаться как из основной памяти (ее размер большой, но читать переменную из нее долго), либо из кеша. Объем кеша намного меньше, но зато доступ к переменной, помещенной в кеш гораздо быстрее.
Соответствено если вы помечаете переменную ключевым словом volatile, то она каждый раз вычитывается из RAM и никогда не помещается в CACHE. Это весьма времязатратно. Но при этом, вы избегаете явления когда разные потоки "делят" между собой эту переменную, переменная записывается в различные cash и разные потоки будут иметь разное значение одной в результате переключения потоков в момент выполнения неатамарной операции.
Если вы уберете ключевое слово volatile, то переменная будет записываться в кеш.
Фактически, в кеш хранится только копия переменной, а сама переменная хранится в RAM. У каждого потока свой CACHE со своей копией переменной. Управление в ходе выполнения программы переключается между потоками. Это происходит и у вас. И если операция неатамарна, как у вас (ведь ++ это операция это нужно сначала вычитать значение, потом инкрементировать значение, а позже записать ее в переменную), то с большой долей вероятности возникнет такая ситуация (в случае отсутствия volatile): один из потоков инкрементирует переменную  **utteranceCount** но не успевает присвоить новое значение - этой переменной, а управление перехватывает следующий поток. И при таком режиме
работы utteranceCount будет расти куда медленней, чем при правильном режиме работы. И политики наговорят больше чем должны.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ!!! Тоесть просто получается, что другой поток просто ждет как бы, пока действие над переменной полностью завершится!? Ведь все равно эти переменные принадлежат объекту класса и не должны делиться между потоками?

Comment: В языке нет средств для управления размещением данных в кэше. Этим занимается аппаратура процессора (MMU - memory management unit), а не софт (на уровне софта (в ОС) можно лишь запретить помещать данные из  некоторых диапазонов адресов в кэше). На самом деле volatile говорит **компилятору**, что при каждом использовании переменной в программе нужно использовать инструкции для ее чтения-записи из памяти (обращения к памяти обычно проходят через кэш), а не оптимизировать это использование, пытаясь разместить переменную в регистре процессора. Обычно использование volatile замедляет программу.